# When there is a third degree price discrimination, why is the total MR curve kinked at the top?

Tags: price-discrimination

[image: third degree price discrimination market]

I know that the total MR = MR of student + MR of adult, but wy is it kinked at the top?

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is just a horizontal sum. At the very top of your graph, only adult has a part of its curve above 10.25. So when your summing horizontally student =0  Adult = x, This changes once you are below 10.25, then all of a sudden you have student = x  and adult = x. This additional amount from student causes the kink. If pretend student was always =0 then the total on the right would be identical to adult.

I hope this helped. I'm sorry if it's not phrased better.

Comment: This is the correct answer.